# Change specific datapoint in xarraxy

Tags: python, python-xarray

I want to replace some data in an xr.DataArray is not based on a condition but at a specific point in place over multiple time points (not at all points as you do with `.where`.

As an example:
I have the following DataArray

```
anom = xr.DataArray(data=np.random.rand(4,4,4),
                  dims=["lat", "lon", "time"],
                  coords={"lat": [-180 ,-90 , 0, 90], "lon": [-90, -45, 0, 45], "time": [1, 2, 3, 4]})

new = [.5, .5, .5]
```

And want to check the values at `lat=20`, `lon=20`, over three `time` steps and take the maximum value. I can select this using `.sel` and then compare the values with `.where` like this:

```
x = anom.sel(lat=20, lon=20, method="nearest").sel(time=slice(2, 4))
x = x.where(x > new, other=new)
```

But I'm stuck at this point. I don't know how I now override the values in anom (specifically at `anom.sel(lat=20, lon=20, method="nearest").sel(time=slice(2, 4))`) with the new `x` values.

Comment: Sorry, not completely clear what you want to do. Do you want to only replace the values in `anom` at `time=slice(2, 4)`?

Comment: I want to replace the values of `anom.sel(lat=20, lon=20, method="nearest").sel(time=slice(2, 4))`  with the new `x` values. I'll also update the question to make it more clear.